# Kinetic energy seen from two frames of reference

Tags: energy, inertial-frames, galilean-relativity

The kinetic energy of two particles (moving in free space) depends on the frame in which you look at the particles. So does total momentum.

If I'm standing in the center of mass of the two particles, they have less energy as when looked at from a frame moving along with one of them.

This means that in a the co-moving frame they can heat up something (say a water reservoir) to a higher temperature than a water reservoir in the COM.

So it depends where I put the reservoir. If I put it in the COM, the total kinetic energy will heat up the water less than when I put it in a frame in which one of the masses is at rest.

Now I can somehow feel what's going on but I don't know how to put it in words. Does anyone have them? If I accelerate both to equal but opposite momenta in the COM frame, I will put less energy in them  then accelerating one to their relative velocity in a frame in which one is at rest. But so what? It's like a reservoir falling on the COM between two free particles in a gravity field. A reservoir falling along on one of the particles will be heat up more than one in the COM. Is there potential energy at work?

Comment: "If I'm standing in the center of mass of the two particles, they have less energy as when looked at from a frame moving along with one of them." Are you sure about that?

Comment: @BobD Not anymore! But it seems so. It seems that from the COM they have half the energy as seen from each moving mass.

Comment: Consider two equal masses moving in the same direction with the same velocity with respect to the ground

Comment: @BobD Ah! I get you! In the COM they have zero energy. A reservoir in the COM will not be heated. But one on the ground will.

Comment: @BobD No. I dont get you. In their COM, the bath will not be heated. Neither in one of the masses. Zero energy in both. Only the masses hitting a bath on the ground. Is that always the same?

Comment: Yes it is zero in both. That’s my point. You said it would be less in the COM frame.

Comment: You create perpetuum  mobile  by chancing the coordinate system, this is impossible

Answer (score 1):

The fact that they have different KE in different frames doe not mean that the energy trasferred (by collision for example) will be different. This assumption (your third paragraph) does not follow from the second paragraph. In one frame they may transfer all their energy and in a different frame they may transfer just part of it.
If you do the actual calculation you will see that the energy transfer is the same in all reference frames. This question (in different versios) was answered several times on this site. For your case, in the frame in which the "container" is fixed in the COM, after a perfectly innelastic collision the three objects will be at rest so all the KE is converted in heat. However, if you analyse the situation in a different frame, the container and the objects will be moving after the collision so not all the initial KE is transfered to heat.

Comment: This is what I overlooked indeed. In the COM all kinetic energy is converted, while in the resframe of one of the two the water temperature will increase with the same amount and get extra overall momentum. It's quite simple actually. I felt it but couldn't lay a finger. Their relative motion stays the same.

Comment: @Felicia The answer above is not correct. It is based on a misreading/ misunderstanding of your question. Your conclusion that the reservoir will be heated less if it is at rest in the COM is perfect;ly correct. This is most obvious if you have only one mass: if the reservoir is at rest in the COM the kinetic energy will actually be zero in this case, so it will not be heated at all. But it will be heated if it is at rest in any other reference frame. See also my own answer in this respect.

Answer (score 0):

Consider for the sake of the argument two equal masses $m$  moving with velocities $v$ and $-v$ in the center of mass. The kinetic energy in the center of mass is then

$$T_{COM}=2\cdot\frac{m}{2}v^2 = m\cdot v^2 $$

If the center of mass moves itself in the lab frame with velocity $V$, the total kinetic energy is instead

$$T_L=\frac{m}{2}(V+v)^2 +\frac{m}{2}(V-v)^2 =  m\cdot V^2 + m\cdot v^2 $$

So the kinetic energy in the lab frame is the kinetic energy of all masses in the center of mass frame plus the kinetic energy of the sum of all masses moving with the velocity $V$ of the center of mass in the lab frame.

Generally, the kinetic energy is always a minimum in the COM frame. In every other reference frame the kinetic energy is higher. So the OP is correct to conclude that an inelastic absorption of the kinetic energies of the masses will heat up a water bath less if it is at rest in the center of mass compared to being at rest in any other reference frame.

Comment: But suppose we are in outer space. If we place a reservoir of water in their COM, the two masses will heat up the bath less than if we place the reservoir at rest wrt one of them.

Comment: @Felicia Yes, you have only one mass moving now, but this mass has twice the velocity so four times the kinetic energy, so in total you would have twice the kinetic energy in this case

Comment: consider yourself in a satellite going around the earth in 90 minutes. With your telescope you see your parents, freezing in their house, so you just tell them "I see you moving at 27000km/h why do you not go just  get in your cold bathtub and warm it up with this awful big energy your bodies have? "

Comment: @Felicia A reference frame is not a container in which you put something. "Placing a reservoir in their COM"  does not mean anything. You can analyse a situation fromthe COM frame or from the lab frame but no object is "placed" in a specific (and unique) frame.

Comment: @nasu Sure you could have the container at rest in the COM in one case and at rest with regard to one of the masses in the other. Assuming the kinetic energy of the masses is completely absorbed  by the container (assumed to be infinitely heavy) in either case, it will be heated by different amounts.

Comment: @nasu As an analogy, if you crash two identical cars into a wall with speed $v$, the wall will be heated only by half the amount compared to crashing one car with speed $2v$

Comment: @Thomas No, the energy will not be totally absorbed for all the cases. Assuming that, will break conservation of momentum. So it is a wrong assumption. And yes, the container can be at rest in various refernce frames but you cannot "place it in a reference frame". It is "in" all possible frames at the same time.

Comment: @Thomas The discussion was about the same event as seen from different frames. Not about  different scenarios seen from the same frame. At least, this is what I understood about the OP and this what my answer was about.

Comment: @Thomas Your example does not refer to same event as seen from two different frames but to completely different scenarios as seen from the same frame. For each of the two scenarios the energy transfered will be the same no matter what reference frame you use for the analysis.

Comment: @nasu An infinitely heavy container will not have any kinetic energy after a fully inelastic collision. All the energy of the projectile will be converted into heat. Momentum is conserved anyway (like it is conserved in an elastic collision when throwing a ball against a wall)

Comment: @nasu quote: "At least, this is what I understood about the OP and this what my answer was about"  Then read the question of the OP again  *So it depends where I put the reservoir. If I put it in the COM, the total kinetic energy will heat up the water less than when I put it in a frame in which one of the masses is at rest* The OP is referring to two different scenarios not the same event.

Comment: @Thomas And this "putting the reservoir" does not make sense, as I already mentioned so it is not relevant.

Comment: @Thomas "If I'm standing in the center of mass of the two particles, they have less energy as when looked at from a frame moving along with one of them". Obviously it refers to looking at the same event from two different frames. "Putting" the reservoir is irrelevant as it is your example with cars coliding with each other or with a wall.